# Scala. Load from Mongo vs. load from persistance

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark

Step 1.

I load data from Mongo to RDD in such a way:

1. `var buff = new ListBuffer[item]`
2. Fill buff via reading from Mongo
3. `data1 =  sc.makeRDD(buff).setName(name).persist(MEMORY_ONLY)`

Everyhing is working.

Step 2.

I save this data to persistance file (folder) :

```
 data1.saveAsObjectFile(fileName)
```

In further I can read data from file rather than from Mongo

```
data2 = sc.objectFile(fileName).persist(MEMORY_ONLY).setName(name)
```

Everyhing is working.

QUESTION.

Why `data1` is 8 (eight!!!)  times slower than `data2` ???

For example,

```
         *data1.count() - 9.5 sec*

         *data2.count() - 1.2 sec*
```

Memory is enough.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: it's a common bad practice to use `var` instead of `val`. About your question, have you tried to use `HDFS` instead of a local directory?

Comment: Thank you. I know this bad practice, but this the case.

Comment: As for the question. I haven't tried to use Hadoop HDFS because RDD from local directory works perfect. I want to accelerate RDD from Mongo.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and there is not enough details about your configuration to give you a definitive answer but most likely everything can be reduced to a simple difference in execution:

- `sc.makeRDD` has to:

  - fetch data to the `Driver` to create `buff`
  - serialize items in the `buff` and transfer to respective workers
  - *find size of each partition and reduce partial results*
- `sc.objectFile` has to:

  - *read data for each partition*
  - *find size of each partition and reduce partial results*

Stages marked with italics are perform in parallel. Otherwise processing is performed at least partially on a driver and doesn't fully utilize the cluster.

As you can see it makes `makeRDD` / `parallelize` significantly less efficient and passing data via `Driver` can easily become a bottleneck. These methods are useful mostly for testing, parallelizing small support collections or range-like objects not to handle heavyweight data.

There are a least two MongoDB connectors out there which can be used instead:

- [Spark-Mongodb](https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB)
- [Official MongoDB Connector for Hadoop](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I'll try to re-work the code according to your tips and report about the results later.